# Text scaling in the SVG image

Tags: svg

Good afternoon!
I have SVG image:
I need the automatic calling text inside of rectangles and automatic scaling of rectangles.

```html
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 640 640" width="640" height="640">  
  <!--A SECTION-->
  <g id="A1">
    <rect x ="0" y ="0" width="40" height="120" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
    <text x="20" y="60" stroke-width ="2" id="T_A1" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" style="fill:black">A1</text>
  </g>
  <g id="A2">
    <rect x ="50" y ="0" width="40" height="120" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
    <text x="70" y="60" stroke-width ="2" id="T_A2" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" style="fill:black">A2</text>
  </g>
  <g id="A3">
    <rect x ="100" y ="0" width="40" height="120" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
    <text x="120" y="60" stroke-width ="2" id="T_A3" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" style="fill:black">A3</text>
  </g>
  <g id="A4">
    <rect x ="150" y ="0" width="40" height="120" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
    <text x="170" y="60" stroke-width ="2" id="T_A4" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" style="fill:black">A4</text>
  </g>
  <g id="A5">
    <rect x ="200" y ="0" width="40" height="120" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
    <text x="220" y="60" stroke-width ="2" id="T_A5" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" style="fill:black">A5</text>
  </g>
  <g id="A6">
    <rect x ="250" y ="0" width="40" height="120" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
    <text x="270" y="60" stroke-width ="2" id="T_A6" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" style="fill:black">A6</text>
  </g>
  <g id="A7">
    <rect x ="300" y ="0" width="40" height="120" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
    <text x="320" y="60" stroke-width ="2" id="T_A7" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" style="fill:black">A7</text>
  </g>
  <g id="A8">
    <rect x ="350" y ="0" width="40" height="120" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
    <text x="370" y="60" stroke-width ="2" id="T_A8" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" style="fill:black">A8</text>
  </g>
  <g id="A9">
    <rect x ="400" y ="0" width="40" height="120" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
    <text x="420" y="60" stroke-width ="2" id="T_A9" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" style="fill:black">A9</text>
  </g>
  <g id="A10">
    <rect x ="450" y ="0" width="40" height="120" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
    <text x="470" y="60" stroke-width ="2" id="T_A10" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" style="fill:black">A10</text>
  </g>
  <g id="A11">
    <rect x ="500" y ="0" width="40" height="120" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
    <text x="520" y="60" stroke-width ="2" id="T_A11" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" style="fill:black">A11</text>
  </g>
  <g id="A12">
    <rect x ="550" y ="0" width="40" height="120" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
    <text x="570" y="60" stroke-width ="2" id="T_A12" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" style="fill:black">A12</text>
  </g>

  <g id="Z1">
    <rect x ="600" y ="0" width="120" height="120" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
    <text x="660" y="60" stroke-width ="2" id="T_Z1" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" style="fill:black">Z1</text>
  </g>
  
  <!--B SECTION-->
  <g id="B1">
    <rect x ="0" y ="140" width="80" height="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />    
    <text x="40" y="165" stroke-width ="2" id="T_B1" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" style="fill:black">B1</text>
  </g>
  <g id="B2">
    <rect x ="0" y ="190" width="80" height="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
    <text x="40" y="215" stroke-width ="2" id="T_B2" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" style="fill:black">B2</text>
  </g>
  <g id="B3">
    <rect x ="0" y ="240" width="80" height="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
    <text x="40" y="265" stroke-width ="2" id="T_B3" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" style="fill:black">B3</text>
  </g>
  <g id="B4">
    <rect x ="0" y ="290" width="80" height="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
    <text x="40" y="315" stroke-width ="2" id="T_B4" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" style="fill:black">B4</text>
  </g>
  <g id="B5">
    <rect x ="0" y ="340" width="80" height="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
    <text x="40" y="365" stroke-width ="2" id="T_B5" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" style="fill:black">B5</text>
  </g>
  <g id="B6">
    <rect x ="0" y ="390" width="80" height="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
    <text x="40" y="415" stroke-width ="2" id="T_B6" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" style="fill:black">B6</text>
  </g>
  <g id="B7">
    <rect x ="0" y ="440" width="80" height="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
    <text x="40" y="465" stroke-width ="2" id="T_B7" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" style="fill:black">B7</text>
  </g>
  <g id="B8">
    <rect x ="0" y ="490" width="80" height="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
    <text x="40" y="515" stroke-width ="2" id="T_B8" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" style="fill:black">B8</text>
  </g>
  <g id="B9">
    <rect x ="0" y ="540" width="80" height="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
    <text x="40" y="565" stroke-width ="2" id="T_B9" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" style="fill:black">B9</text>
  </g>
  <g id="B10">
    <rect x ="0" y ="590" width="80" height="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
    <text x="40" y="615" stroke-width ="2" id="T_B10" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" style="fill:black">B10</text>
  </g>

  <!--C SECTION-->
  <g id="C1">
    <rect x ="300" y ="190" width="40" height="120" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
    <text x="320" y="255" stroke-width ="2" id="T_B1" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" style="fill:black">C1</text>
  </g>
  <g id="C2">
    <rect x ="350" y ="190" width="40" height="120" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
    <text x="370" y="255" stroke-width ="2" id="T_C2" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" style="fill:black">C2</text>
  </g>
  <g id="C3">
    <rect x ="400" y ="190" width="40" height="120" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
    <text x="420" y="255" stroke-width ="2" id="T_C3" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" style="fill:black">C3</text>
  </g>
  <g id="C4">
    <rect x ="450" y ="190" width="40" height="120" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
    <text x="470" y="255" stroke-width ="2" id="T_C4" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" style="fill:black">C4</text>
  </g>
  <g id="C5">
    <rect x ="500" y ="190" width="40" height="120" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
    <text x="520" y="255" stroke-width ="2" id="T_C5" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" style="fill:black">C5</text>
  </g>
  <g id="C6">
    <rect x ="550" y ="190" width="40" height="120" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
    <text x="570" y="255" stroke-width ="2" id="T_C6" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" style="fill:black">C6</text>
  </g>
  <g id="C7">
    <rect x ="600" y ="190" width="40" height="120" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
    <text x="620" y="255" stroke-width ="2" id="T_C7" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" style="fill:black">C7</text>
  </g>
  <g id="C8">
    <rect x ="650" y ="190" width="40" height="120" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
    <text x="670" y="255" stroke-width ="2" id="T_C8" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" style="fill:black">C8</text>
  </g>

  <!--D SECTION-->
  <g id="D1">
    <rect x ="300" y ="320" width="40" height="120" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
    <text x="320" y="385" stroke-width ="2" id="T_D1" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" style="fill:black">D1</text>
  </g>
  <g id="D2">
    <rect x ="350" y ="320" width="40" height="120" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
    <text x="370" y="385" stroke-width ="2" id="T_D2" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" style="fill:black">D2</text>
  </g>
  <g id="D3">
    <rect x ="400" y ="320" width="40" height="120" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
    <text x="420" y="385" stroke-width ="2" id="T_D3" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" style="fill:black">D3</text>
  </g>
  <g id="D4">
    <rect x ="450" y ="320" width="40" height="120" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
    <text x="470" y="385" stroke-width ="2" id="T_D4" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" style="fill:black">D4</text>
  </g>
  <g id="D5">
    <rect x ="500" y ="320" width="40" height="120" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
    <text x="520" y="385" stroke-width ="2" id="T_D5" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" style="fill:black">D5</text>
  </g>
  <g id="D6">
    <rect x ="550" y ="320" width="40" height="120" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
    <text x="570" y="385" stroke-width ="2" id="T_D6" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" style="fill:black">D6</text>
  </g>
  <g id="D7">
    <rect x ="600" y ="320" width="40" height="120" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
    <text x="620" y="385" stroke-width ="2" id="T_D7" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" style="fill:black">D7</text>
  </g>
  <g id="D8">
    <rect x ="650" y ="320" width="40" height="120" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
    <text x="670" y="385" stroke-width ="2" id="T_D8" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" style="fill:black">D8</text>
  </g>

  <!--E SECTION-->
  <g id="E1">
    <rect x ="200" y ="510" width="40" height="120" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
    <text x="220" y="575" stroke-width ="2" id="T_E1" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" style="fill:black">E1</text>
  </g>
  <g id="E2">
    <rect x ="250" y ="510" width="40" height="120" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
    <text x="270" y="575" stroke-width ="2" id="T_E2" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" style="fill:black">E2</text>
  </g>
  <g id="E3">
    <rect x ="300" y ="510" width="40" height="120" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
    <text x="320" y="575" stroke-width ="2" id="T_E3" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" style="fill:black">E3</text>
  </g>
  <g id="E4">
    <rect x ="350" y ="510" width="40" height="120" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
    <text x="370" y="575" stroke-width ="2" id="T_E4" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" style="fill:black">E4</text>
  </g>
  <g id="E5">
    <rect x ="400" y ="510" width="40" height="120" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
    <text x="420" y="575" stroke-width ="2" id="T_E5" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" style="fill:black">E5</text>
  </g>
  <g id="E6">
    <rect x ="450" y ="510" width="40" height="120" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
    <text x="470" y="575" stroke-width ="2" id="T_E6" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" style="fill:black">E6</text>
  </g>
  <g id="E7">
    <rect x ="500" y ="510" width="40" height="120" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
    <text x="520" y="575" stroke-width ="2" id="T_E7" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" style="fill:black">E7</text>
  </g>
  <g id="E8">
    <rect x ="550" y ="510" width="40" height="120" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
    <text x="570" y="575" stroke-width ="2" id="T_E8" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" style="fill:black">E8</text>
  </g>
  <g id="E9">
    <rect x ="600" y ="510" width="40" height="120" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
    <text x="620" y="575" stroke-width ="2" id="T_E9" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" style="fill:black">E9</text>
  </g>
  <g id="E10">
    <rect x ="650" y ="510" width="40" height="120" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
    <text x="670" y="575" stroke-width ="2" id="T_E10" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" style="fill:black">E10</text>
  </g>
  <g id="E11">
    <rect x ="700" y ="510" width="40" height="120" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
    <text x="720" y="575" stroke-width ="2" id="T_E11" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" style="fill:black">E11</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

And have problems with the text scaling inside of these rectangles, for example:

[image: picture_1]

How can I resolve the issue with scaling the text in such SVG and also solve the problem with scaling rectangles, when I resize the form with SVG image:

[image: picture_2]

Comment: How is this a c# question? What are you stuck with?

Comment: Draw an extra line, use it for a ``textPath`` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/textPath

Comment: Please, can you write an example, for two rectangles, for example?